# Flask Server running only on localhost

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, ssh, portforwarding

I am trying to build an automatic cat feeder that uses flask as the server. when I go to a certain webpage on my raspberry pi, `127.0.0.1:5000/open` to be exact, the servo moves without issue. On other devices on my network, the site can't be reached, so I'm assuming I didn't make it available to the local network. I'm following [this tutorial](http://blog.oscarmorrison.com/how-to-make-a-rpi-powered-wifi-pet-feeder/).
there is a dead link for the python server code so [here is his github](https://gist.github.com/oscarmorrison/552a9a9fc2664bd3578cece680d77c9c).

Answer (score 1):

Use 0.0.0.0 as the ip in the init function
`app.run('0.0.0.0', 8080, debug=True)`

Because 127.0.0.1 is only for local development (only that machine)